# Forge 1.12.2. Мод не видит кириллицу

Tags: unicode, кириллица, minecraft, forge

Хочу написать мод, который меняет все некультурные слова на культурные при отправке сообщения. Игрок отправляет сообщение с матом, а на самом деле отправляется уже без мата.

Вот что я уже написал:

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import net.minecraftforge.client.event.ClientChatEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;

@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, name = ExampleMod.NAME, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
public class ExampleMod {
    public static final String MODID = "mymod";
    public static final String NAME = "My Mod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    @Mod.EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onClientChat(ClientChatEvent event) {
        String originalMessage = event.getMessage();

        String modifiedMessage = originalMessage
                .replaceAll("мат1", "культурное1")
                .replaceAll("lol", "lmao")
                .replaceAll("мат2", "культурное2");
        
        event.setMessage(modifiedMessage);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что мод успешно меняет все латинские выражения (например, `lol` на `lmao`), но не меняет кириллицу. Я пробовал использовать unicode escape, однако это не дало никаких результатов. В чём проблема?

PS. На форумах, посвящённых Minecraft, не отвечают из-за устаревшей версии Forge.